How to align table and other content within table when using p{}?
Minimal reproducible example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|p{7cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}}
\hline 
& Nitrogen global: industrial and intentional fixation of N & Tg of N
$\text{year}^{-1}$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}35\\ 62\end{tabular}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Output: 
The data from table within table and other content within table are not aligned. How to align that?

Try \begin{tabular}[t] instead of \begin{tabular}[c]

@Stephen That does not change anything.

@YH - Did you try making the change to the "outer" or to the "inner" tabular environment?

You just need \newline.
I adjusted a bit the widths so the table fits in the standard margins. In the narrow third column I'd set \raggedright.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|p{7cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.4cm}|p{1cm}}
\hline
& Nitrogen global: industrial and intentional fixation of N & Tg of N
year$^{-1}$ & 35\newline 62
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}



By default, within a given row of a tabular environment, the contents of an "inner" tabular environment in one column is centered vertically relative to the reference line in the other columns. The reference line of the contents of a cell in a plain p-type column is the first, or top, line.
As has already been pointed out in a comment, you need to change the optional positioning information of the tabular environment in column 3 from c (for "center", the default) to t (for "top").

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}  % optional, for '\ce' macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % optional, for '\unit' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.5cm}|p{7cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm} }
\hline 
& Nitrogen global: industrial and intentional fixation of \ce{N}
& \unit{\tera\gram} of \ce{N} per year 
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 35 \\ 62 \end{tabular} 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Instead of inserting tabular in cell, you may use \makecell macroofmakecell` package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}           % new
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % added option 
\usepackage{siunitx}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ p{0.5cm}|p{7cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm} }
    \hline 
    & Nitrogen global: industrial and intentional fixation of \ce{N}
    & \unit{\tera\gram} of \ce{N} per year 
    & \makecell[t]          {35 \\ 62}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

With \makecell the table code is a wee bit shorter :-).

